# Android Studio ArcticFox on Apple M1 keep using Intel arch

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Beta, but AS keep using Intel architecture.
Anybody knows how to solve that ?
[Activity Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Razk.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Arctic Fox Beta versions they provide separate builds for `Mac (Intel)` and `Mac (Apple Silicon)`, which means you need to download Apple Silicon version for the Apple M1.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/04/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-15.html

> To use it, you need to download from:
> https://developer.android.com/studio/archive and look for Mac (Apple
> Silicon), and you need to use Gradle 6.9-rc1+ .